# bypass initializing a variable

Tags: java, initialization

I'm just messing around with Java code to see what I can and can't do. I've come across an issue with a String variable I have created and it says it might not have been initialized. I know what the problem is and why it may not have been initialized but I can't find out how to fix it, I've tried placing the code in different spots, creating or removing strings and nothing works. It all leads back to the same problem.
Methods Code:

```
public class BankAccount {
    private int balance;
    private String name;

    public BankAccount(String n) {
        n = name;
    }

    public void deposit(int dep) {
        balance = balance + dep;
    }

    public void withdrawl(int wit) {
        balance = balance - wit;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Tester Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        int dep;
        int wit;
        int d;
        String dw;
        String alm;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Name Of Bank Account: ");
        String name = input.next();
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount(name);

        while(true) {
           System.out.println("Open Account? (y/n): ");
           String open = input.next();

           if (open.equals("y")) {
                System.out.print("\f");
                System.out.println("Account Open!");
                break;
           } else if (open.equals("n")) {
                System.exit(1);
           } else {
                System.out.print("\f");
                i++;
                System.out.println("Incorrect Syntax");
                System.out.println("Attempts: " + i);
           }
        }
        while(true) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Your balance is " + account.getBalance());
            if (account.getBalance() == 0) {
                System.out.print("\f");
                System.out.println("It seems you don't have any money in your account..");
                System.out.print("Would you like to deposit some? (y/n): ");
                alm = input.next();
            } else {
                System.out.print("\f");
                System.out.println("Would you like to do anything with your account " + name + "? (y/n)");
                alm = input.next();
            }
            while (true) {
                if (account.getBalance() > 0) {
                   if (alm.equals("y")) {
                       System.out.print("What would you like to do? (deposit/withdrawl): ");
                       dw = input.next();
                       break;
                   } else if (alm.equals("n")) {
                       System.exit(1);
                   } else {
                       System.out.print("\f");
                       System.out.println("Incorrect Syntax");
                   }
                }
                if (account.getBalance() == 0) {
                    if (alm.equals("y")) {
                       System.out.print("\f");
                       System.out.println("How much money would you like to deposit?");
                       System.out.print("Amount: ");
                       dep = input.nextInt();
                       account.deposit(dep);
                       break;
                   } else if (alm.equals("n")) {
                       System.exit(1);
                   } else {
                       System.out.print("\f");
                       System.out.println("Incorrect Syntax");
                   }
                }
            }
            if (dw.equals("deposit")) {
                System.out.print("\f");
                System.out.println("How much money would you like to deposit?");
                System.out.print("Amount: ");
                dep = input.nextInt();
                account.deposit(dep);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's at the bottom where it says:

```
if (dw.equals("deposit")) {
                System.out.print("\f");
                System.out.println("How much money would you like to deposit?");
                System.out.print("Amount: ");
                dep = input.nextInt();
                account.deposit(dep);
            }
```

"Variable dw may not have been initialized" is the error I get. How can I bypass this if statement so it ignores it unless the balance is greater than 0?

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize it when you declare it:

`String dw = "";`